# How to add image on canvas using Render object in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add image on canvas(color:White) using Render object in flutter.
Initially I want the canvas to be white in color and Rectangular in shape.
After I load an image, That image should be in top canvas.
I dont know how to do it.Please help me to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by canvas? Are you talking about [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html)?

Comment: No, I dont want to use CustomPaniter. I want to create canvas using Render Object

Comment: Are you refering this [canvas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html)?

Comment: how do you want to create a `Canvas` using `RenderObject`? are you extending `RenderProxyBox`?

Comment: I want to create empty canvas extending RenderBox.then I need to load image on top of canvas.

Comment: use something like `class TestWidget extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {....` then

Comment: but honestly why not to use a normal `CustomPaint` instead? why to make such a pain with a custom `RenderObject`?

Comment: I heard Using Render object is better customPaint.Thats why I want to create canvas using renderBox. I have created canvas using render object. but dont know how to set height,width,color for it. Please refer below link and suggest any ideas.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63074083/how-to-set-height-width-and-color-for-renderbox-in-flutter

Comment: extend `RenderProxyBox`, not `RenderBox`